# Missing queryFn error when using useQuery

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, react-query

As the title suggests, I am new to using useQuery and the associated libraries, I am trying to use it to fetch data and then populates a list of fields that I have created
However when I run it I get this error after it makes two requests

```
Missing queryFn index.js:1
    e index.js:1
    onError query.js:356
    reject retryer.js:67
    run retryer.js:132
    (Async: promise callback)
    run retryer.js:116
    Retryer retryer.js:156
    fetch query.js:330
    executeFetch queryObserver.js:199
    onSubscribe queryObserver.js:40
    subscribe subscribable.js:16
    useBaseQuery useBaseQuery.js:60
    React 5
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:468
    React 3
    workLoop scheduler.development.js:417
    flushWork scheduler.development.js:390
    performWorkUntilDeadline scheduler.development.js:157
    (Async: EventHandlerNonNull)
    js scheduler.development.js:180
    js scheduler.development.js:645
    Webpack 21
```

As far as I can tell I have passed in a query function so I am very confused why this error is showing I can see the server is receiving the requests and seemingly sends it, I have tested elsewhere and server does send it so it has to be with my code right?

```
const URL = 'http://localhost:3500/monster';
const fetchMonster = async (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    let res = await fetch(`${URL}/${id}`);
    if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }
    return res.json;
};
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: {
        queries: {
            retry: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
            refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
        },
    },
})

function EditMonster(props) {
    let { slug } = useParams();
    return (
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
            <Query
                slug={slug} />
        </QueryClientProvider>
    )
}

function Query(props) {
    const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery('monster', fetchMonster(props.slug))

    if (isLoading) return 'Loading...';
    if (error) return 'An error has occured: ' + error.message;

    return (
        <AttributeFields name='Edit Monster' method='PATCH' monster={data} />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> useQuery('monster', fetchMonster(props.slug))

this code does not pass a function to useQuery - it immediately invokes the function. What you want is:

`useQuery('monster', () => fetchMonster(props.slug))`

As a side note, dependencies to the query function should go to the query key:

`useQuery(['monster', props.slug], () => fetchMonster(props.slug))`

Comment: lol as I read this comment I thought "hey that looks like TkDodo's recommended query key structure" and then I looked at the user who answered this question and it's the same. Great advice here: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/effective-react-query-keys#structure

Answer (score 18):

For those searching for answers from 2022, you simply need to pass your first parameter to useQuery as an array like so:

```js
useQuery(['monster'], () => fetchMonster(props.slug))
```

and your request works.

Comment: Yep, that's the one.

Answer (score 1):

The thing we are missing here is that you might have set the value for 'monster' query somewhere in your code. If the query value is set before it's been fetched we get this issue.

Comment: Any idea how to fix this issue? I assumed that the cache will just return the value that was previously fetched

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it need a function but passing the function you are calling the function.

It should be like eg:

```js
const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery('monster', () => fetchMonster(props.slug))
```

just rap `fetchMonster` function in side in to a arrow function
that's all.

Answer (score 0):

two reasons may cause this issue, the first one is not using the async function and the second is not passing query function dependency with the query key.
finally, the query function should be typed like this

```
const { data, isFetching, refetch } = useQuery(
  // dependency is passed here
  ["user data", session?.user._id],

  // async fucntion
  async () => await getUserData(session?.user._id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

On my end, I wanted to pass `id` as param in useQuery. Here it is my implementation.

```
=> hooks.js

const useListingById = (id) => {
    return useQuery(["listings", id], () => listingServices.getListingById(id));
};
```

```
=> [id].js

const { data, error, isFetching } = useListingById(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const fetchMonster = async ({queryKey}) => {
    const id = queryKey[1];
    console.log(id);
    let res = await fetch(`${URL}/${id}`);
    if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }
    return res.json;
};    

const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery(['monster',props.slug], fetchMonster);
```